# ASP.NET MVC JsonResult and AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the most straight forward way to use `AuthorizeAttribute` and `JsonResult` together so that when the user is not authorized the application returns a Json error rather than a log in page?

The two things I am currently considering are extending `AuthorizeAttribute` or just making a new attribute that implements `IAuthorizationFilter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `AuthorizeAttribute` from your Action.

Then in the first lines of your action, insert this:

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    return Json("Need to login");
```

or return whatever message you want.

Comment: That just seems like bad design unless I refactor that logic out to another class. What if I need to change the error message for multiple actions? I don't see that happening, but you never know...

Comment: If you want, you could create your own attribute that checks for authorized users and if they aren't, instead of redirecting, return a json object.

Comment: If you need to have multiple error messages, just use a resource to hold it or make it a static string that you can refer when returning your jsonresult.

Comment: @ajma any thoughts how to create such attribute which returns json result? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997467/how-to-create-custom-jsonauthorize-attribute-to-secure-actions-which-returns-json

Comment: You'd probably have to create a custom attribute and the attribute could return the error message.