# How to create custom JsonAuthorize Attribute to secure actions which returns JsonResults?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was thinking how to correctly secure JsonResult action with custom attribute instead of doing kind of this on each action like saying here [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult and AuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825550/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-and-authorizeattribute)

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    return Json("Need to login");
```

But the question is how could i create such attribute which would return Json.
So i've started from that:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class JsonAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
            }
            IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;

            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            { 
               //? 
            }

            //Need to return json somehow ?
        }
    }
```

Bot how i may return json result from such attribute? any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `ActionFilterAttribute` which allows you to return a result without using the `httpcontext.response.write` or anything.

```
public class JsonActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = "Need to login." };
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1 way is to override AuthorizeAttribute.HandleUnauthorizedRequest

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    throw new CustomUnauthorizedException();
}
```

... And then in your Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception error = Server.GetLastError();
    if (error is CustomUnauthorizedException) {
        if (AjaxRequest(Request)) {
            ... return Json response.
        } else {
            ... redirect
        }
    }
}
```

So you can throw the exception anywhere in your codebase and you've centralized the handling of that exception in Global.asax

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it works for me

```
 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
 {
   dynamic ResponseObj = new JObject();
   ResponseObj.Message = "Authorization has been denied for this request.";
   string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ResponseObj);
   actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
      Content = new StringContent(jsonString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")
     };
 }
```